# Library for model helpers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to keep EntityFramework model class clean and only present database structure,
So if it needs helper methods, I may add a seperate class, example:

```cs
public class Book{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BookHelper{
    public Book Entity;
    public List<Book> OtherSeries(){
        var books =  Entity.Author.Books;
        books.remove(Entity);
        return books;
    }
}
```

Is any Library to standalize this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do this. But I don't think they are called/considered standard. It's just your own preference. But whatever you choose to do, don't put so many methods into 1 class, it breaks the Single Responsibility.

First, Use extension method

```
public static class BookExntensions
{
    public static List<Book> OtherSeries(this Book book)
    {
        var books =  book.Author.Books;
        books.remove(Entity);
        return books;
    }
}
```

Second, Use Helper class like the way you did.

Third, Use Helper with generic type, so you can reuse some of the code.

```
public class EntityHelper<T>
{
    private T Entity;
}
public class BookHelper : EntityHelper<Book>
{
    public List<Book> OtherSeries()
    {
       var books =  Entity.Author.Books;
       books.remove(Entity);
       return books;
    }
}
```

There are still more ways to do, but I'll leave them out.